# Find all solutions of $y^2 dx + (e^x - y)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find all solutions of:

$y^2 dx + (e^x - y)dy = 0$

So I take:

$M = y^2$

$N = e^x - y$

And I see that:

$\frac{M}{dy} = 2y$

$\frac{N}{dx} = e^x$

I'm therefore looking for an integrating factor:

$$ \displaystyle e^{\int \frac{1}{y^2}(e^x - 2y) dy} = e^{\int \frac{e^x - 2y}{y^2}dy} = e^{-2ln(y) - \frac{e^x}{y}}$$

And at this point I think it might be too complicated and I probably do something wrong.

Comment: Try taking the substitution $y=e^x(1+z)$.

Comment: Seeing that the terms are polynomial up to $e^x$, one might try $u=e^x$. With $dx=e^{-x}du=du/u$ this gives a rational polynomial expression, but increases the degree. So one might try to go in the other direction with $u=e^{-x}$, so that now $dx=-e^xdu$. This gives a simpler version of the expression, you should be able to see the next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide equation by $y$.
Then easy get that integrating factor of $y^2 dx + (e^x - y)dy = 0$ is
$$\mu=\frac{e^{-x}}{y}$$
and all solutions
$$\ln y-e^{-x}y=C$$

Comment: I don't think it works. When I divide by $y$ I get $y dx + ((\frac{e^x}{y} - 1) dy) = 0$. Taking the integrating factor as you metioned gives me $\frac{1}{e^x} dx + \frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{1}{e^x \cdot y} dy = 0$. Now, derivatives are not equal: one is $0$ and the other is not. The differential equation is not exact.

Comment: I get $ye^{-x}dx+(1/y-e^{-x})dy=0$. Then $M'_y=e^{-x}$, $N'_x=e^{-x}$. Derivatives are equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider the equation as
$$y^2\,x'+e^x -y=0$$
Let $x(y)=\log \left(\frac{y}{u(y)}\right)$ to make it more than simple

Comment: I don't know how to find the antiderivative of $log(\frac{y}{u(y)})$ with respect to y

Comment: @mathman12. $x=\log(y/u)=\log(y)-\log(u) \implies x'=1/y - u'/u$

Comment: Ok, then I get in te end that: $u' = \frac{1}{y}$, but how to undo the substitution?

Comment: $x = log(\frac{y}{u}) \iff e^x = \frac{y}{u} \iff u = \frac{y}{e^x} \iff u' = \frac{1}{e^x}$?

Comment: is that something like this?